# What's the meaning of "You'd be so nice to come home to"?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Helen Merrill - [You'd Be So Nice To Come Home To](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkybDxsdBaQ) - live 1960

> **You'd be so nice to come home to**
> You'd be so nice by the fire
> While the breeze on high sang a lullaby
> You'd be all that I could desire 
> ...

What's the meaning of "You'd be so nice to come home to"? Does that mean "It would be so nice if you came home."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, a parent might say "I don't want to come home to a big mess." This is a similar situation where, "to come home to" a mess means "to come home and *find*" a mess there.

The concept of "coming home to someone" is fairly common in English, especially in poetic or romantic writing. Originally this concept comes from the traditional roles where a man might come home to see his wife after a long day at work, as opposed to coming home to an empty house. Now days, "coming home to someone" is based on the image of two people in a committed relationship; one comes home after a long day (at work, perhaps) and the other person is there waiting for them.

**"You'd be so nice to come home to" means something like "it would be so nice to be able to come home and have you there."**

Answer (score 1):

No. It means that it would be very nice for me (the person singing) to come home, if you were there in my home.